# Unable to load mod_alias in apache

Tags: apache2, localhost

Runing the command `sudo service apache2 restart` output :

```
 * Restarting web server apache2                                         [fail] 

* The apache2 configtest failed.

Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/alias.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_alias.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_alias.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Please add the result of following commands ```grep  --line-number --context=3 "mod_alias" /etc/apache2/apache2.conf``` and ```stat -L /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_alias.so``` - it looks like specified directory of ```mod_alias.so``` is wrong.

Comment: running the command display error:  root@kumar-desktop:/home/kumar# stat -L /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_alias.so
stat: cannot stat `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_alias.so': No such file or directory

Comment: Try the ```grep``` command with ```sudo```.

With result of second command ```sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-gget install --reinstall apache2``` has high probability to fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Working fine.  credits to [@A.B.](https://askubuntu.com/users/367165/a-b)

Following Steps :

1.If not, backup your configurations and install apache2 again via

sudo mv /etc/apache2 /etc/apache2.bak
sudo apt-get purge apache2
sudo apt-get install apache2

2.Restart your server and check if the problem is solved

sudo service apache2 restart

If you get a error message like

The apache2 configtest failed. Output of config test was: apache2:
Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error
on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/alias.load: Cannot load
/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_alias.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2
modules/mod_alias.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
directory Action 'configtest' failed. The Apache error log may have
more information.

3.reinstall apache2-bin via

sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2-bin

because the file /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_alias.so is part of the package apache2-bin